# How to use 'self' in jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, self

I made simple color change function and organize it as object. but how to use `self` in the object?

this is object that I made and first and second is working well, while 3rd isn't working..

```js
var Color = {
    textColor:function (color){
        $('body').css('color', color);
    },
    backgroundColor:function (color){
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
    },
    inputColor:function (color){
        $(self).css('backgroundColor', color);
    }
}
```

If I use commented out query, it works well while `Color.inputColor('color')` not working. I want to organize it as object.

```js
function highlightInput(self){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // $(self).css('backgroundColor', 'lightyellow');
        Color.inputColor('lightyellow');
        $(self).blur(function(){
            // $(self).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
            Color.inputColor('white');
        });
    });
}
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to just pass it as a parameter to `inputColor` (and to any other functions of `Color` that need a reference to `self`):

```
var Color = {
    textColor:function (color){
        $('body').css('color', color);
    },
    backgroundColor:function (color){
        $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
    },
    inputColor:function (color, self){
        $(self).css('backgroundColor', color);
    }
}
```

and

```
function highlightInput(self){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Color.inputColor('lightyellow', self);
        $(self).blur(function(){
            Color.inputColor('white', self);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is not a valid variable. You are trying to use `this`.

You have two ways to solve it:

1) By declaring the property `self` outside and using it into your function:

```
var Color = {
  self: this,
  textColor:function (color){
    $('body').css('color', color);
  },
  backgroundColor:function (color){
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
  },
  inputColor:function (color){
    $(self).css('backgroundColor', color);
  }
}
```

2) By using arrow functions:

```
var Color = {
  textColor:function (color){
    $('body').css('color', color);
  },
  backgroundColor:function (color){
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
  },
  inputColor: (color) => {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', color);
  }
}
```

PS: You better call your variable `_this` or something different than `self` since you can have troubles messing up with `window.self`.

Comment: And what if he is trying to use [self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)? `self` != `this`

Comment: You mean ```window.self```?

Comment: Yes, when ommiting the `window` is still valid and equals `window`

Comment: I see, then he will need to pass ```window.self``` during object creation.